Flutter loading the ENV file in bitbucket pipeline
Loading the ENV file in bitbucket-pipelines is not working.
const localEnvPath = 'local_variables/.env.local';
const devEnvPath = 'local_variables/.env.dev';
const qaEnvPath = 'local_variables/.env.qa';
const prodEnvPath = 'local_variables/.env.prod';

String? getEnvPath() {
  const envKey = String.fromEnvironment('ENV_KEY');

  switch (envKey) {
    case 'local':
      return localEnvPath;

    case 'dev':
      return devEnvPath;

    case 'qa':
      return qaEnvPath;

    case 'prod':
      return prodEnvPath;

    default:
      return null;
  }
}

I here have a method which returns the path for the env file by getting the build time variable --dart-define=ENV_KEY=something , and load the env according to the path. like this
  final envPath = getEnvPath();

  if (envPath == null) {
    throw Exception('Error! Env not found');
  }

  await dotenv.load(fileName: envPath);

but the prob is in bitbucket pipeline, since the env files are git ignored there won't be such env's in the path and I believe it is breaking when trying to load await dotenv.load(fileName: envPath);. How can I fix this? I've also tried adding the repository variables. Still ain't working. Btw I'm using flutter_dotenv package to load the env file.
